How use shared memory created in Python code and reading in Cpp
Below is my python code which is writing data in shared memory and it is successfully writting in  /dev/shm/my_shared_memory
write_data.py
import mmap
import os

# Create a shared memory segment
os.unlink("/dev/shm/my_shared_memory")

shm_fd = os.open("/dev/shm/my_shared_memory", os.O_CREAT | os.O_RDWR, 0o666)
os.ftruncate(shm_fd, 4096)  # Set the size of shared memory

# Memory-map the shared memory segment
shm = mmap.mmap(shm_fd, 4096)

# Write data to shared memory
message = "This is sample data"
shm.write(message.encode())

# Close the shared memory segment
shm.close()
os.close(shm_fd)

Below is cpp code which is going to read shared memory. after running that I am getting "Error opening shared memory: Invalid argument"
read_shared_memory.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cerrno> 
int main() {
    // Open the shared memory segment
    int shm_fd = shm_open("/dev/shm/my_shared_memory", O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (shm_fd == -1) {
        perror("Error opening shared memory");
        return 1;
    }

    // Memory-map the shared memory segment
    void* addr = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        std::cerr << "Error mapping shared memory" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Read data from shared memory
    std::string message(static_cast<char*>(addr));

    // Output the message
    std::cout << "Received message from Python: " << message << std::endl;

    // Unmap the shared memory segment
    if (munmap(addr, 4096) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error unmapping shared memory" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Close the shared memory segment
    if (close(shm_fd) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error closing shared memory" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

I am new to cpp and shared memory and not sure where I am getting wrong.

EINVAL for shm_open() means wrong name. Check that the c++ application has access to the path, also check user name.

Thanks. In some blog I read that by default shm_open takes each pathname /foo and is translated into /dev/shm/foo.
